# Enable Virtual Machine

Tags: virtualization

I have a **Gateway LT41P05u mini** laptop and I want to install a virtual machine on **virtual box** but it does not allow me.

I tried to enable virtualization but there is no option available in **Bios**.

Is their any hope that I might be able to run virtual  machine on this laptop?

Comment: If there is no option it likely means your hardware does not support the feature, but it's not a requires feature, to run a virtual machine.  Gateways are not known for being feature rich

Comment: What error, and what are the host and guest?

Answer (score 0):

The option is likely under a different name.

> Look for an option named “Intel Virtualization Technology,” “Intel VT-x,” “Virtualization Extensions,” “Vanderpool,” or something similar.
>   ([Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/))

Comment: Looks like the processor - the N2805 supports it. Might be disabled in BIOS tho. You can still run some sorts of vms without it tho